# What is the meaning of `struct point makepoint(int,int)`?

Tags: c, function, struct

As the title says in C what is the meaning of `struct point makepoint(int,int);` where `makepoint(int,int)` is a function that returns a `point` structure?

I can understand its point in the language C...?

Answer (score 2):

```
struct point makepoint(int,int);
```

is the (prototype) declaration for the function `makepoint()`.

Comment: thank you, i have come from java to c and thus prototypes are new to me